# Before/after iOS tool

Tags: ios, iphone, uiimageview, uiviewcontentmode

I want to make something like this:

[image]
[Reference of image.](https://goo.gl/eYovnX)

What I do: two `UIImagesView`, one with `UIViewContentModeLeft` and another with `UIViewContentModeRight`. I have a slider where I can change image frames. The solution seems to be ok, but I am not sure if this is the "right" one. Other suggestions are welcome.

Thanks!

Comment: You could probably google out existing components for this,  like https://www.cocoacontrols.com/controls/wcbeforeafter , inspire yourself from their source code or do come back with more detailed and specific-issue question.

Answer (score 1):

use single `Imageview` for your concept it is my suggestion If you feel free use this else use your concept else go some thirdparty, where you need for modify the transparent, add the one `Transparent UIView` above the `ImageView` . set the frame as of `Transparent UIView` for `Show` as `(0, 0, ImageView.frame.size.width/2,ImageView.frame.size.height)` , for `Hide` `(ImageView.frame.origin.X - 40, 0, ImageView.frame.size.width/2,ImageView.frame.size.height)`

for example

*To Show*

```
TransparentView.hidden = NO;
TransparentView.alpha = 0.1;
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
     TransparentView.frame =   CGRectMake(0, 
                                          0, 
                                          ImageView.frame.size.width/2,
                                          ImageView.frame.size.height);
    TransparentView.alpha = 1.0f;
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    // do some
}];
```

*To hide*

```
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{
    TransparentView.frame = CGRectMake(0 - self.view.frame.size.width, 
                                       0, 
                                       ImageView.frame.size.width/2,
                                       ImageView.frame.size.height);
    [TransparentView setAlpha:0.1f];
} completion:^(BOOL finished) {
    TransparentView.hidden = YES;
}];
```